# Implement Terms and Conditions for IdentityServer (something similar to Consent Service)

Tags: identityserver4

Our applications do not require consents from the users, whereas they require terms and conditions (tandc) to be accepted before accessing the application. We have two tables to track tandc, something like this:-

```
TersmAndConditions
-TermsAndConditionsId
-Message
-IsActive

UserTermsAndConditions
-UserId
-TermsAndConditionsId
-AgreedDate
```

**Current approach:**
Every time we come up with a new tandc (which happens when there is a major change in the application), we insert a record in the TermsAndConditions table. When a user signs into our application, right after the authentication we check whether there is a record in the UserTermsAndConditions table for the authenticated user, if yes, we issue tokens, and if there is no record we show the tandc page, and when the user agrees the tandc, we insert a record into the UserTermsAndConditions table.

We're planning to do the same by coming up with a new implementation of IConsentService instead of the DefaultConsentService. Is this a right approach?

Comment: Are these terms for each Client?

Comment: Yes, some clients will not have tandc enabled.

Comment: If accepting the latest T&Cs is part of *your* authentication process then it seems like a decent approach to put it inside your IDP. I'm not sure about changing the meaning of the consent concept in OAuth though. I'd just add it to the authentication UI flow but keep it separate from client consent.

Comment: @mackie I can add it part of the authentication UI flow, but when the user agrees t&c, there should be a way to track that the user already passed the authentication step... do you think adding a new authentication cookie scheme for t&c (like 2fa) will work?

Comment: @Gokulnath yes that makes sense.

Comment: I actually have the same need, I wonder if you were able to implement it thru the consent flow, which makes sense to me too :D

Comment: @KatLimRuiz I didn't use the consent flow, I implemented it separately. Right before issuing the token I check the tandc, and issue the token only if tandc had been accepted.

Comment: @Gokulnath and what if they were not accepted?

Comment: @fvl if it's not accepted, I show a page to accept the t and c, and only only if they accept it I issue the authentication cookie. I ended up building a simple state machine to track every step (username validation, password validation, OTP validation, expired/expiring password checks, t and c, etc.,) before issuing authentication cookie. Used another signin cookie to track the step, and in the server side I checked whether an event is allowed based on the current state